# How to configure tomcat web.xml and tomcat-users.xml to secure a tomcat page

Tags: xml, tomcat, authentication

I want to secure my admin pages in tomcat with web.xml and tomcat-users.xml.It doesn't works.

Here is my contents of my tomcat-users.xml

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <tomcat-users>
 <role rolename="webadmin"/>
 <user username="kumar" password="kumar" roles="manager"/>
 </tomcat-users>
```

and contents of WEB-INF/web.xml

```
    <resource-env-ref>
    <description>abc.com/</description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>player</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase</resource-env-ref-type>
     </resource-env-ref>


     <security-constraint>
     <display-name>player</display-name>
     <web-resource-collection>
     <web-resource-name>personal</web-resource-name>

     <!-- Define the context-relative URL(s) to be protected -->


     <url-pattern>abc.com</url-pattern>
     <!-- If you list http methods, only those methods are protected -->

     <http-method>DELETE</http-method>

     <http-method>GET</http-method>

     <http-method>POST</http-method>

     <http-method>PUT</http-method>

  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
     <!-- Anyone with one of the listed roles may access this area -->
     <role-name>webadmin</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<!-- Default login configuration uses form-based authentication -->
<login-config>
     </form-login-config>-->
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>player</realm-name>
</login-config>

<!-- Security roles referenced by this web application -->
 <security-role>
<role-name>webadmin</role-name>
 </security-role>
```

please let me know what needs to be added in these xmls.

Comment: is password prompted?

Comment: no i didn't see any login page at all

Comment: I doubt its because of your url pattern. Every thing else looks fine to me. I believe you have restarted the server as well.

Comment: what should be given in the url pattern. please let me know

Comment: try giving '/'. Just to narrow down the problem.

Comment: do you want me to replace / in the url-pattern instead of abc.com or do you want me to do in web.xml. please let me know

Comment: <url-pattern>abc.com</url-pattern> to <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> in your web.xml

Comment: Did you succeeded using URl pattern like  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> or  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>?

Comment: @gyan i didn't get succeed in either ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as access to the tomcat manager GUI is considered, there is no role as "manager" to set in tomcat-users.xml.

you have to specify one of these roles.

You can find the role names in the web.xml file of the Manager web application. The available roles are:
•**manager-gui** — Access to the HTML interface.
•**manager-status** — Access to the "Server Status" page only.
•**manager-script** — Access to the tools-friendly plain text interface that is described in this document, and to the "Server Status" page.
•**manager-jmx** — Access to JMX proxy interface and to the "Server Status" page.

have a look into this link for further info,
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html

I hope it helps, thanks.

Comment: Please let me know, do you want me to replace manager with  •manager-status or •manager-gui or •manager-script or  •manager-jmx

Comment: yes, please change the role as manager to as "manager-gui" in order to access the tomcat manager web app UI. in tomcat-users.xml,  it would be something like this.. <user username="username" password="yourPassword" roles="manager-gui"/>   then restart the tomcat, access the web-app and enter the username and yourPassword and you will be able to access manager web app UI. I hope it helps thanks.

Comment: I have installed Two Apache tomcat. It is working for tomcat webpage which i running in 8080, but it is not working for webpage which i running in 80. In 80,i have uploaded videos, which i really want to protect it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, there are two ways you can have multiple tomcat on a single machine. Depending upon the type of approach you took, you need to set things in order to have the required effect. If you have created an instance and have set the CATALINA_BASE directory then you must have copied the "conf" folder as well which includes your tomcat-users.xml too, in this case your username/password will work on this instance as well. IF you have installed another tomcat server separately then you need to again make an entry in the tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml as you did previously. I hope it helps.thanks.